# Cancel zoom from dbclick event onmap in google maps version 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I initiallize a map in my application like this:

```
function doLoad() { 
     var parnitha= new google.maps.LatLng(38.155428,23.718739);
     var myOptions = {
      zoom:16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      center: parnitha,
      disableDefaultUI: true, 
              navigationControl: true, 
              scrollwheel: false, 
              navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 
    }
     map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); }.
```

With double click on the map, it making zoom and i don't want this, because i want to use dbClick event for other reason.Please help me to remove the default dbClick event on the map.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Today I am also at this strange problem with V3. The double click is not been disabled by method (google.maps.Map).setOptions( disableDoubleClickZoom: false ). I should change to (google.maps.Map).setOptions( disableDoubleClickZoom: true )!!!

Answer (score 13):

Try setting `disableDoubleClickZoom` to `true` in the map options object. It's also documented at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Update your myOptions object to look like this (note the first option):

```
 var myOptions = {
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  zoom:16,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  center: parnitha,
  disableDefaultUI: true, 
          navigationControl: true, 
          scrollwheel: false, 
          navigationControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 
}
```